# Launch $EDITOR from git-filter-branch --msg-filter

Tags: git, shell

I want to change all my commits messages to translate them in another language.

I know I can achieve this using git-filter-branch --msg-filter, but I don't want to replace the messages with any pattern, instead, I want to open each commit message in my editor, change it and save, like I do when I use reword in git-rebase --interactive.

Comment: why are you not using rebase then?

Comment: Rebase don't preserve merge commits. See my reply to willoller below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'cat > ~/msg && 
  vim >&2 <&1 ~/msg && 
  cat ~/msg' HEAD^^^^..HEAD
```

This will allow you to edit with vim the messages of the last 4 commits. Add `-f` if you're doing this a second time to overwrite the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you rebase your branch, you can edit any/all of the commit messages.

The tricky thing about Git is it uses the commit messages as part of the commit itself, so your branches will diverge.

Just do (on your branch):

```
git rebase -i master
```

or if you want to preserve merge commits (thanks danillonunes and Adam D.)

```
git rebase -i master --preserve-merges
```

When you are presented with the editor, change the first column from `pick` to `edit` and you will get a chance to change every commit message.

Comment: The trouble with rebase is that it doesn't preserve merge commits. Now that you said that, I search at the git docs and found that there's a --preserve-merges parameter available, so it should work with git rebase -i --preserve-merges. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I didn't know about not preserving merge commits; my git repos look like redwoods.

Comment: `git rebase --preserve-merges`